# Internet works through a router but not when connected directly to the ethernet port in macbook pro

Tags: proxy, ethernet, ping, network-adapter, macbook-pro

I'm in an engineering college and we connect to internet via proxy servers.
We have an ethernet port in each room to connect to the internet.
I have an ubuntu pc and I can use an RJ45 cable to connect my pc to the ethernet port and ping successfully(get replies) to the proxy server, or connect a router to the port and then use WiFi or ethernet cable to connect my pc to router and then again I'm able to ping the proxy servers.
I got a macbook pro recently and since there is no ethernet interface, I'm using a [rapoo XD200C hub](https://www.amazon.in/Adapter-Reader-Charging-MacBook-Chromebook/dp/B07WDWGD62?th=1) to connect the macbook to internet via RJ45 cable.
Now here is the problem

> I'm not able to recieve replies for ping when I connect the rapoo hub directly to ethernet port and connect the hub to my pc and pings to proxy servers result in time outs.

> But when I'm using a router in between my pc and the ethernet port, everything seems to work just fine, and I'm getting replies on the ping to proxy servers.

What should I do?

Comment: When connected directly to the room's Ethernet port, does the MBP get link? That is, does the Ethernet interface in the rapoo port expander show as "Connected" in macOS? Does the Mac get a correct DHCP lease on that interface? Does pinging the proxy server work when all other networking interfaces on the Mac are disabled?

Comment: Hi @Spiff, yes the USB 10/1000 port expander shows connected on macOS and it does get a correct DHCP lease, I've tried renewing the lease and it assigns the new address correctly. I'll try and let you know about pinging the server after disabling all other interfaces.